# Inhereting and migrating an old ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net

I've found myself having to re-publish an old ASP.NET website with all the company's years of data on a new server, but only have an SQLdump file [no problem there] and what looks like a pre-compiled app with no source code [from what I read online].

This is the directory structure:

[image]

As I've never worked with microsoft stuff before, I'd like to ask if this is workable data or if there's something missing, and if everything is there the question is how do I get it back up and running?

I'm on Ubuntu 16 where I've already installed dotnet-sdk-2.1.4 following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x#install-net-core-for-ubuntu-1404-ubuntu-1604-ubuntu-1610--linux-mint-17-linux-mint-18-64-bit) and I've already installed nginx and mysql, everything ok there. I'd need to get the ASP.NET webapp back up to then point nginx to it as a reverse proxy.

Thanks and sorry for the basic question.

Comment: Ok thanks I see. And once I do fire up a windows VPS, is this workable data or am I missing something? This is all I've been given by the old hosting company.

Comment: This looks like it could be an old webforms web app. You *may* be able to deploy this as is with the appropriate .net framework installed. You may need to change the database connection strings in the web.config file to reflect the connection to the new DB server.. As most of the app is complied you won't be able to maintain this without the original source code.

Comment: Looking at this: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1961, it appears you can't run a webforms app on .net core. Which is the article you linked to.

Comment: Thanks for that. Was the last one a question? So aside from the linux issue, this data should be enough to run, on windows say?